# need help about writing xpath which contain dynamic values in ID attribute

Tags: selenium

HTML code:

```
<div id='abcd12$selenium450'>
```

where the numeric value ie 12 or 450 are changing frequently but the string part remains constant.
I have tries with contains(), but I am confused bcz the xpath should contain abcd as well as selenium.
Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `starts-with` and `contains`  both.

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'abcd') and contains(@id,'selenium')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in multiple ways.

- **`starts-with` and `contains` CSS**:

```
div[id^='abcd'][id*='selenium']
```

- **`starts-with` CSS**:

```
div[id^='abcd']
```

- **`starts-with` and `contains` xPath**:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'abcd') and contains(@id,'selenium')]
```

If element is something like this then you can use multiple `contains`

**HTML**:

```
<div id='12abcd$selenium450'>
```

- **`contains` and `contains` xPath**:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'abcd') and contains(@id,'selenium')]
```